# Power BI bar/ line chart formatting

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, linechart

Is there any options in power BI bar/ line chart for conditional formatting of background color? For example if the y axis is between 0-10 then the background is red between 10-20 yellow and so on?

I have two fields in y-axis

Comment: do you mean gradient background like here: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Gradient-Background/m-p/308840 ?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

An option is to do this manually by setting the background to be transparent or off, then add rectangles underneath with desired colours/sizes. It won't be dynamic though.

Or you can set a background image for the plot area.

Comment: @Tina - please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all - or follow-up.